# Passing variable containing format in struct.unpack format specifier

Tags: python-2.7

I have length of a string a variable such as,

```
variable = len(another_variable)
```

is there any method I can pass this 'variable' as format specifier in struct module. In normal situation it works like

```
list = sturct.unpack('2L', another_variable)
```

But I want something like,

```
list = struct.unpack('variable', another_variable)
```

or may be I can use some part of 'another_variable' stored in 'variable' and I could use it like.

```
list = stuct.unpack('L, variable', another_variable)
```

Is there any method that I could pas a variable containing the length in format specifier and if there is then how to pass it with format of string or integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do that.

```
struct.unpack(('<{0}L'.format(variable/4)), another_variable)
```

This works with python 2. For python 3 see [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html)